# how to do other jquery thing after some jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I am using PHP. I want finish the jQuery AJAX process, (finish process and **after data back to the main page**) .

Then do the next jQuery thing. Any ideas on how to do it?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "page1.php", 
  dataType: "html",
  type: 'POST', 
  data: "value=" + value, 
  success: function(data){
    //some process
  }
});//ajax1
$.ajax({
  url: "page2.php", 
  dataType: "html",
  type: 'POST', 
  data: "value=" + value, 
  success: function(data){
    //some process
  }
});//ajax2
$.ajax({
  url: "page3.php", 
  dataType: "html",
  type: 'POST', 
  data: "value=" + value, 
  success: function(data){
    //some process
  }
});//ajax3

// finish all the 3 ajax process, do the below code
$(".page").css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using jQuery 1.5 or better, you can use the heavenly [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when) construct, which uses the [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) concept first implemented in that version of jQuery.  You can run a function (or several functions) when all of several AJAX requests have completed.

So your code would look like this:

```
$.when($.ajax({
    url: "page1.php",
    dataType: "html",
    type: 'POST',
    data: "value=" + value,
    success: function (data) {
        //some process
    }
}), $.ajax({
    url: "page2.php",
    dataType: "html",
    type: 'POST',
    data: "value=" + value,
    success: function (data) {
        //some process
    }
}), $.ajax({
    url: "page3.php",
    dataType: "html",
    type: 'POST',
    data: "value=" + value,
    success: function (data) {
        //some process
    }
})).then(function () {

});
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! $.when() seems like it'd be really handy!

Comment: +1 for when! never heard of it before, I'm sure I'll use this :)

Comment: Note that .then() takes TWO functions: one to run when everything goes right, and the latter to handle error conditions.  That can be really useful for debugging client/server things.

Comment: Ooh, spiffy! This makes me want to upgrade :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have an arbitrary number of ajax operations, you can do something like this:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push($.ajax(...));
arr.push($.ajax(...));
/* put as many ajax operations as you want into arr */
$.when.apply(arr).then(function() { /* on success */ },
                       function() { /* on error */ });
```

This is my favorite technique for synchronizing multiple ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record so that the pre-jQuery-1.5 answer is here, too:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "page1.php", 
  dataType: "html",
  type: 'POST', 
  data: "value=" + value, 
  success: function(data){
    $.ajax({
      url: "page2.php", 
      dataType: "html",
      type: 'POST', 
      data: "value=" + value, 
      success: function(data){
        $.ajax({
          url: "page3.php", 
          dataType: "html",
          type: 'POST', 
          data: "value=" + value, 
          success: function(data){
            // finish all the 3 ajax process, do the below code
            $(".page").css('display','block');
          }
        });//ajax3
      }
    });//ajax2
  }
});//ajax1
```

Hopefully, if nothing else this illustrates the value of the new jQuery 1.5 way of doing things :-)